# Spring Logback multitenancy implementation with custom config per tenant

Tags: spring, maven, logback, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement a multitenency compatible logging which logs each tenants log in a different file **AND** can be configured for each tenant individually.

I'm using Spring Boot in a Maven build with SLF4j and Logback.

To achieve a different file for each tenant i'm using MCP to set a tenant identifier for each request.

```
 MDC.put("tenant", "tenant-" + tenant_id);
```

It's now easily possible to logout the tenant like this

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>%X{tenant} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

However, I'm not able to put them in different files. Moreover I do not have any concept on how to define the logback xml per tenant.

I cannot find any good examples to go beyond the basics - do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck, you're gonna have to implement your own appender. It shouldn't be too difficult though. The interface is pretty straight forward:

```
    public interface Appender<E> extends LifeCycle, ContextAware, FilterAttachable<E> {

    /**
     * Get the name of this appender. The name uniquely identifies the appender.
     */
    String getName();

    /**
     * This is where an appender accomplishes its work. Note that the argument 
     * is of type Object.
     * @param event
     */
    void doAppend(E event) throws LogbackException;

    /**
     * Set the name of this appender. The name is used by other components to
     * identify this appender.
     * 
     */
    void setName(String name);
}
```

You'll get a `LoggingEvent` in `doAppend` that has this method: `getMDCPropertyMap` from which you can discriminate which file to append to.
If I were you I'd probably wouldn't get on the nitty-gritty of handling the files and would actually have a map of regular `RollingFileAppender`. So your doAppend method could look like this:

```
private Map<String, Appender> appenders = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

void doAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
    String tenant = event.getMDCPropertyMap().get("tenant");
    Appender appender = appenders.get(tenant);
    if(appender == null) { //may need to synchronize, careful
        appender = initTenantAppender(tenant);
        appenders.put(tenant, appender);
    }
    appender.doAppend(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I just found the "SiftingAppender" do you think the appender provides enough for my purpose?

Comment: yeah, it basically does what I describe, you can implement your appender based off of that one

Comment: Thanks! - Last question: If I want to have another log level for TenantA than TenantB has - is it sufficient so set the log level programatically at the beginning of each request? Do i run into problems with parallel requests here?

Comment: yeah, I mean, each appender can have it's own configuration, they could be any arbitrary combination of appenders with they're own levels.